# Reading space delimited integers

Tags: c#, performance, input

I am to read a bunch of space delimited integers (35 33 2 3 251 etc.) from stdin. The input can be millions of ints long, so I want to make sure the read is as fast as possible. And currently, I am pretty sure this is not the case :)

This is what I've got:

```
string[] stringArr = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
var len = stringArr.Length;
int[] intArr = new int[len];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    intArr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(stringArr[i]);
```

The above does the trick, but it seems really clumsy to me. And I haven't really worked a great deal with stdin in C# in the past, but I imagine there are quite a bit faster ways to do this?

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: I imagine the question is you want this to be fast. Is the ordering of the integers important?

Comment: This might belong to [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @L.B of course not! The question is implicit. But in case someone else can't see this, I will update the post.

Comment: @Dominik: That makes sense. Can I transfer the q there?

Comment: @ChristoferOlsson I think you can initiate a vote to move it, I'm not sure how though.

Comment: If it works, leave it alone, unless it's making you wait long enough to be a bother.

Comment: You can do that by implementing a more efficient `Split` method yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the optimal answer, but it's in the right direction as it avoids a 'costly' `Split` and parse:

```
var str = "10 20 13 45 78";

var ints = new List<int>(str.Length / 2); // Approximating the likely final size of the int array
int result = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
{
    var c = str[i];

    if(c == ' ')
    {
        ints.Add(result);
        result = 0;
        continue;
    }

    result = 10 * result + (c - '0');
}

    // We didn't add the last char yet
var lastChar = str[str.Length - 1];

if(lastChar != ' ')
{
    ints.Add(result);
}
```

After that, you can experiment with loop unrolling, unsafe memory access and different heuristics of estimating the final size of the list of ints (or perhaps with lazily yielding them with `yield return` instead of buffering it all). All of that depends on what your date looks like and how big it is.

Note that this assumes all your integers are positive, but adding support for negative numbers is trivial.

Comment: It really puzzled me that C# does not seem to have an equivalent to Java's scanner class. What also puzzles me is that this was somewhat slower than what I had previously :)

Comment: Scratch that. It is actually about 5 times faster. Makes much more sense.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this best by reading character by character and just doing the math:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (int i in Read(Console.In))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}

static IEnumerable<int> Read(TextReader rdr)
{
    int ch;
    bool neg = false;
    int value = 0;
    int count = 0;

    while (-1 != (ch = rdr.Read()))
    {
        if (ch == 9 || ch == 10 || ch == 13 || ch == 32)
        {
            if (count > 0)
                yield return neg ? -value : value;  
            count = 0;
            value = 0;
            neg = false;
        }
        else if (count == 0 && ch == '-')
        {
            neg = true;
        }
        else if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        {
            count++;
            value = value*10 + (ch - '0');
        }
        else
            throw new InvalidDataException();
    }

    if (count > 0)
        yield return neg ? -value : value;  
}
```

Comment: i think Console.In doesn't handle bytes and is problem. It handles chars. it may replaced by Console.OpenStandardInput.

Comment: @serbasi I was reading characters, not bytes.  Thus the use of TextReader rather than OpenStandardInput which returns a stream.